# Position child div outside parent div (left/top)

Tags: html, css, layout, position

I am creating a horizontal accordion timeline but am having issues with child div within them. Here is an example - without the jQuery in place:

http://jsfiddle.net/QLfU4/

The GREEN div is placed within the 3rd 'pink' vertical panel div. I want this to centre to the 3rd div - that is to have it floating out over 2nd div - outside the parent div. Using left/top will only position it to the outside of the page. I've have played around with 'position' on outer and inner divs but with no luck.

Would anyone out there have a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mess around with `margin: 0px;` you can give this negative values such as `margin-left: -5px;`